# Populate a list using jQuery from an AJAX as autocomplete

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got a JSON file with a list of items. Each item has an ID and a name such as

```
{ID : 11, Name: 'item 1'}
```

I'm using the jQuery Mobile framework where I need to put a textbox where users can start typing an item name and the list should populate items from the file with the letters inside (some sort of autocomplete).

BTW - the list is VERY long (thousands of items) so I wouldn't like to load it all at once.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use any server-side language? If all you have is JavaScript, it's impossible to pick entries from a single file without loading the entire file.

Comment: No. I just have a json file. Could I load it into memory and then filter it? I don't want to populate the list with the values - just the needed ones.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way to do it.

Comment: Great. Is there any way to automatically filter them, or I just need to go one by one and filter? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function to return the result set based upon the "terms" in the phrase entry.

An example would be to use the `source:` of the jQuery UI Autocomplete and then filter your json data (cached on load?) based on the occurence. Something similar to breaking the phrase with a string split and iterating over that like with `jQuery(':contains(text)')` comes to mind.

If your json is an array `jQuery.grep()` might be perfectly suited. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep

Here is another example in this question: [How can I "filter" JSON for unique key name/value pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604935/how-can-i-filter-json-for-unique-key-name-value-pairs)

Couple of other options in the answers here: [json jquery filter javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347137/json-jquery-filter-javascript-array)